# A function that is one to one but not onto $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: functions

Can someone please tell me if I can have a function that is one to one but not onto $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$? 
I tried these formulas 
\begin{align*}
F(x) & = x^2+1\\ 
F(x) & = x^2 -1
\end{align*} 
But it always gives me a function that is onto but not not one to one, and I don't want it to be like this.

Comment: Try something that is not continuous. You can always take a bijection from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb N$ and make it miss $1$ by pushing all the values up.

Comment: How can i do it ??

Comment: You’re close. How about something like $F(x)=x^2+\mathop{sign}(x)$?

Comment: will sin or cos or any works in Discrete Mathematics? Because i am new with it .

Comment: Sure, you just have to make sure your answer comes out in the right set, but otherwise go for it. Things like $\cos(\pi n)$ can be a nice shortcut for the equivalent statement written with powers of $(-1)$.

Comment: "not onto $Z$ to $N$" ? I think you mean  from $Z$ into, but not onto $N$. For example $f(z)=2 |z|+17$ if $z\leq 0$ and $f(z)=2 z$ if $z>0$.

Answer (score 8):

If $k\ge 0$, let $f(k)=2^k$. If $k\lt 0$, let $f(k)=3^{-k}$.

Answer (score 1):

f(n) = 3|n| + sign(n), where sign(n) is -1, 0, or 1, according to whether n is negative, zero, or positive. All the positive multiples of 3 will have no preimage.

Answer (score 1):

Take any bijection from $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb N$, and then double the value of the images for every point. It'll still be injective because unique points will have unique images, even after the doubling, but now it misses the odd naturals.

Comment: Or start with any injection and add $1$ to each image.

Answer (score 0):

How about

$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
  n+3,  & \text{if } n \in \{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2\}\\
  n^2+1, & \text{if } n \ge 3 \\
  n^2-1, & \text{if } n \le -3 \\
\end{cases}$

$f(n) = (4+sgn(n))^{|n|}$

$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
  2n+2,  & \text{if } n\ge 0\\
  1-2n, & \text{if } n \lt 0 \\
\end{cases}$